# Issue in taking screenshot in selenium while using chromedriver 73 for chrome version 73

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

When i tried to take screenshot of a webpage using selenium in python, i get error message "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000".

I'm using Chrome version 73, chromedriver version 73.

Note: code was working fine (ie.screenshot)in lower version of chrome and chrome driver.

[**Screenshot of error message**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK4Em.png)

Help me out in fixing this issue for new version of chrome driver.

Thanks in advance

Tags